# C# ProvideX/Sage ODBC driver with JOIN Query

Tags: c#, .net, join, odbc, ssms

I am trying to execute an OdbcCommand with a SQL query containing a simple JOIN (or LEFT JOIN). I get the following error:
`System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [37000] [ProvideX][ODBC Driver]Unexpected extra token: JOIN`

My code looks like this:

```
using var connection = GetOdbcConnection();
connection.Open();

var odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(SqlQueries.SelectItems, connection);

var reader = odbcCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

And `SqlQueries.SelectItems` is:

```
public const string SelectItems = @"SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Key = Table1.Key";
```

If I execute the following query in SSMS, it works fine:

```
SELECT
TOP 10 *
FROM OPENQUERY([DSN_NAME], 'select * from Table1')
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([DSN_NAME], 'select * from Table2')) ON Table1.Key = Table2.Key
```

**HOWEVER**, if I execute the following query in SSMS, I reproduce the exact same error:

```
SELECT
TOP 10 *
FROM OPENQUERY([DSN_NAME], 'select * from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.Key = Table2.Key')
```

I tried the follwing:

1. Executing the exact same query that I used in SSMS (with the OPENQUERY), I get the following error:
   `Unexpected extra token: (`
2. Executing the exact same query that I used in SSMS (with the OPENQUERY), but this time using a `SqlConnection` and a `SqlCommand`:

   1. Without specifying a connection string: I got an error saying that the connection string has to be initialized
   2. With specifying the connection string that I used in my ODBC connection, which is simply `DSN=DSN_NAME`. I don't really know if there is another connection string format for ODBC that could work with `SqlConnection`

I am expecting the ODBC Command to perform a JOIN between both tables and return the results. I don't really know how the ODBC Command translates the SQL query and uses it against ODBC data source, but there must be a way to do it since the join works when using OPENQUERY in SSMS.

The only think that I think of is selecting data from table 1 using one query, then selecting data from table 2 using another query, and then associate them together on the application side; which I don't really want to do for performance purposes (unless I don't have any other choice). This latter solution is also mentioned in the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398296/providex-sage-odbc-driver-with-group-by-and-column-alias).

***NB**: Any simple query like `'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MyParameter = ?'` works fine using the ODBC connection and ODBC Command.*